# Building Docker images with GitLab CI/CD on existing git-runner

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have to build and push docker image via gitlab-ci. I have gone through the official document.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

I want to adopt shell method but my issue is I already had a working gitrunner on my server machine. So what the procedure for it. If I tried to re-register the git runner on the same machine. will it impact the old one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you installed gitlab-runner as a system service and not inside a container, you can easily register another `shell` runner on your server using the command `gitlab-ci-multi-runner register`.

This is indirectly confirmed by the [advanced configuration documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#advanced-configuration), which states that the `config.toml` of the *gitlab-runner* service may contain multiple `[[runner]]` sections.

**Note**: To allow the shell runner to build docker images, you will need to add the `gitlab-runner` user to the `docker` group, e.g.:

```
sudo gpasswd --add gitlab-runner docker
```